# Can't delete a file with nautilus on 12.04 from desktop

Tags: files, delete

[Can't delete a file in nautilus](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21108895/8.png), the delete menu is inactive. What can be a reason? If just selecting a file with a cursor and pressing del on keyboard the file moves to the thash and then I can delete it from trash as usual but not with nautilus direcly from a desktop.

Answer (score 1):

There is not normally a delete in the Nautilus menu.  You have to activate delete by going into nautilus edit->preferences->behaviour.

Comment: It is activated as you see. ... Ok, after rebooting the system, delete menu became active in nautilus http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21108895/9.png, but it would be interesting what was the reason of that bug.

Comment: The bug appeared again, don't know why.

Comment: :)) Well, everything worked from a beginning. This option was active, I thought it was inactive because of a new theme style I've installed. So seems it's a gtk3 theme issue(maybe). Moderator can delete this theme.